# how to iterate through tokenize result in xquery

Tags: xquery

In xquery, I have a unknown length string str="/a/b/c" which I can split by tokenize(str, '/'), but what's the syntax to go through all the elements in tokenize result automatically based on string length?

for example /a/b/c will be a b c and for /a/b/c/d will be a b c d  and so on.

Comment: is there a structure in xquery like in java which is like?

for(int i=0;i<tokenize.length,i++)
output(tokenize[i])

Answer (score 6):

Use a plain old for (FLWOR) loop for this.

```
<tokens>{
 for $t in tokenize("a/b/c/d/e/f/g","/")
 return <token>{$t}</token>
}</tokens>
```